# Disabling navigation for whole feature module in Angular feature-module base application

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Hello Stack Community,

The scenario is following:

Angular app contains of several feature modules. Those modules provides their `RouterModule.forChild(roues)` to define their internal routing and are imported into main app routing in pretty standard way. Minimal example would be:

app.module.ts

```
...
  imports: [
    FeatureModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
       {path: 'rootPath', component: SomeComponent},
       /* Many other routes */
    ])
  ]
...
```

feature.module.ts

```
...
  imports: [
    FeatureRoutingModule
  ]
export class FeatureModule
...
```

feature-routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
    {path: 'featurePath1', component: A},
    {path: 'featurePath2', component: B},
    {path: 'featurePath3', component: C,
      children: [
        {path: 'nested-feature-path1', component: Cc1},
        {path: 'nested-feature-path2', component: Cc2},
      ]
    },
])],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FeatureRoutingModule{ }
```

So, standard setup: `app-module` imports feature modules that each of them defines their own routing modules `.forChild` with nested routes.

Now the task is to temporarily disable access to this module making *minimal* impact on already existing code and routing rules.

- not importing it at all to main `app.module` is not a solution, because app is using some other stuff form it
- not importing module `RouterModule.forChild()` inside feature is not an option, because then internals od it does not compile due to lack of `router-outlet` definition
- guarding paths on feature-module level require to set guard on every single path, because it's not defining his 'root' app, so every entry has to be disabled with some always-false blocking guard
- disabling path from parent level is not possible, as it's a navigable component that's routing module is imported by parent

The least impactful way so far I discovered is just to swap from

`RouterModule.forChild([{ /* Actual routes definition */ }])`

to

`RouterModule.forChild([])`

that effectively hides all exposed feature module routes making them effectively unreachable, but is there some more transparent/declarative way of "turning off" feature modules in a way, that it's obvious for anyone browsing the code, that module is needed but it's internal routing is disabled?

Comment: How about navigation events? You could f.e. check for `NavigationStart` in a central place and check the path, and if it is the feature module you want to disable, then interrupt navigation.

Comment: From technical perspective this makes perfect sense (and I even used this before empty routing array configuration), but as I mentioned, I'm looking for most "declarative" way possible, that even somebody who started his Angular journey one day before would understand.